# How to correctly free all elements of a linked list?

Tags: c, memory, struct, free

I have a structure table which is kind of like a linked list. My goal is to empty whatever is in that table. I think my idea is correct, but it's not working and I do not know why.

```
typedef struct table{
    LIST *top;
    int size;
}TABLE;
```

What I am trying is to take every single thing in the table and apply `free()` to it. And then to set the top of the table to `NULL` so I cannot go through it later and also set the size to 0.

```
void empty_table(TABLE *table) {
    LIST *cur;
    for (cur = table->top; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) {
        if (cur == NULL) return;
        free(cur);
    }
    table->top = NULL;
    table->size = 0;
}
```

Apparently this is not working and I don't know the reason. I tried a simple run and it doesn't even change the size.

```
    // ...
    printf("table has %d elements\n",tab->size);
    empty_table(tab);
    printf("table has %d elements\n",tab->size);
    // ...
```

Here I am testing it where `tab` is a pointer to table.

The output is:

```
table has 5 elements
table has 5 elements
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is right, but the implementation is wrong. In your loop, you are freeing `cur`, and *then* looking at its `->next`. This is undefined behavior because `cur` was just freed.

If you want to free your entire list, you will have to keep another temporary pointer to remember `cur`, and free that only after you advance to the next element in the list. You will not be able to do this with a `for` loop, as the `cur = cur->next` operation cannot be the last one, but must be done before `free()`.

Here's an example:

```c
void empty_table(TABLE *table) {
    LIST *cur = table->top;
    LIST *tmp;

    while (cur != NULL) {
       tmp = cur;
       cur = cur->next;
       free(tmp);
    }

    table->top = NULL;
    table->size = 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't see that, thanks for your answer. I will change it.